# CFO Estimation in LoRa Chirp Signal (Preamble part)

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, fourier, frequency-modulation

I am trying to estimate CFO in LoRa chirp signal (preamble part). I have seen the discussion about CFO on this forum but it is mainly related to CFO estimation in OFDM.
I want to estimate the CFO in a chirp signal using FFT method. Simply taking the FFT of the signal and then taking the Frequency index with highest frequency (argmax).
I have data from real LoRa signal and I know that CFO estimation suffers from many factors but the values that I am getting are no where near to the range of a CFO device (0-20ppm).

Therefore, I generated the synthetic LoRa chirp signal with CFO as expression the reference (1) attached below.

'''

```
import numpy as np

def lora_baseband(fc, BW, SF, phi, num_symbols, sampling_rate, offset_hz):
    symbol_duration = 2**SF / BW  # Duration of one LoRa symbol in seconds
    t = np.linspace(0, symbol_duration, int(symbol_duration * sampling_rate), endpoint=False)
    chirp_signals = []
    for _ in range(num_symbols):
        chirp_signal = np.exp(1j*(-(np.pi)*BW*t+np.pi*(BW/symbol_duration)*(t**2)+(2*np.pi*(fc+offset_hz)*t)))
        chirp_signals.append(chirp_signal)
    return t, np.concatenate(chirp_signals)  # Concatenate the chirp signals for the specified number of symbols


# Parameters for the LoRa-modulated chirp signal
fc = 868e6  # Carrier frequency in Hz
SF = 7  # Spreading factor
BW = 125e3  # Frequency deviation in Hz
phi = -(np.pi)  # Initial phase of the chirp signal
num_symbols = 8  # Number of LoRa symbols to generate
sampling_rate = 2e6  # Sampling rate in Hz
offset_hz=5000

# Generate 10 LoRa-modulated chirp symbols
t_symbol, base_chirp = lora_baseband(fc, BW, SF, phi, num_symbols, sampling_rate, offset_hz)
```

This code generates the chirp signal with 5 KHz CFO ..

[image: 8 LoRa Symbols]

'''

```
# Calculate FFT of the received signal
windowed_signal = base_chirp * np.hamming(len(base_chirp))
fft_result = np.fft.fft(windowed_signal)
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(fft_result), d=1/sampling_rate)  # Frequency values corresponding to FFT
# Find the peak frequency in the FFT result to estimate CFO
peak_frequency_index = np.argmax(np.abs(fft_result))
estimated_cfo = frequencies[peak_frequency_index] 
# Find peaks in the FFT result
'''
```

this provides me an answer of -47851.56 HZ .. which is no where near to the original CFO...

What are the issues here?
Am I committing any fundamental mistake??
Are there any specific CFO estimation methods that need be applied on LoRa modulation?